# Gunzip redirection: "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, gunzip

When I issue the following command:

```
gunzip -c /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz>>/disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000
```

I get the following stderr:

```
gunzip: /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz>>/disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000.gz: No such file or directory
```

I have verified that the input file and the output directory /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp exist. I thought >> would create the file if it didn't already exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces around your >>. Your shell thinks you have one really long filename `/disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz>>/disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000` and is not seeing the >> or the second filename.

you should write:

```
gunzip -c /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz >> /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000
```

Notice the spaces around `>>`

Comment: That works from the command line, but fails as script. The following command lines:

    UZPCMD="gunzip -c "$TMPDIR"/in/"$FILEONLY" >> "$TMPDIR"/outfile.000"
    echo $TMPDIR
    echo $FILEONLY
    echo $UZPCMD

produce the following output - the gunzip command line looks as it should:

    /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp
    part-00006.gz
    gunzip -c /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz >> /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000

However, issuing the command line from the script:

    $UZPCMD

sends line after line of the unzipped file to stdout (as if redirect were ignored).

Comment: @MarkP Then that is a different question than what you asked. Please close out the question and ask a new one, where you can properly format the script.

Comment: Apart from accepting an answer, is there anything I need to do to close out the question?

Comment: @MarkP not really, just create a new question, with your new issue.